# Errors starting with basic xtext

Tags: xtext

Recently I have installed Xtext and tried to run the default Hello world! code using the tutorials available on youtube. However, when I try to run the code I am getting 44 errors.

I am new to using Xtext as well as eclipse. I have tried to reinstall eclipse a lot of times. I have tried with normal version, enterprise version and DSL tools version. But every time I am getting the same errors. Please help me resolve this issue. I tried to find out what these errors meant and how to resolve them over the eclipse community forums but did not find any solution.

All the errors are repetitions of the following two errors.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Duplicate field InternalMyDslParser.FOLLOW_ InternalMyDslParser.java    /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal   line   Java Problem

and

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token "?", delete this token    InternalMyDslParser.java    /org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal   line   Java Problem 
Please Help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199273/discussion-on-question-by-vibhav-errors-starting-with-basic-xtext).